# Is there a limit to the amount of writes to Firebase Firestore collection per second

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a limit to the amount of writes to Firebase Firestore collection per second?
I cannot figure out the latest answer. I have read it is 500 per second, but have also read the limits have been removed?

Comment: Some soft and hard [limits have been removed](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/whats-new-in-firestore-from-cloud-next-and-firebase-summit-2022/), others are still there. The current limits on write operations, can be found in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions

Comment: I don't see anything about 500 writes per second, which i have seen in past documentation. Does that mean that per second write limits have been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the limit you're referring to is this (from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#index_exemptions)):

> If you index a field that increases or decreases sequentially between documents in a collection, like a timestamp, then the maximum write rate to the collection is 500 writes per second. If you don't query based on the field with sequential values, you can exempt the field from indexing to bypass this limit.

The limit is based on "hotspotting" behavior for indexes.  Each partitioned range of values in an index is managed by a shard, which has its own individual write limit.